# Scala spark - count null value in dataframe columns using accumulator

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have this function:

```
def countNullValueColumn(df: DataFrame): Array[(String, Long)] = 
   df.columns
      .map(x => (x, df.filter(df(x).isNull || df(x) === "" || df(x).isNan).count))
```

I'm trying to use an `val counter = sc.longAccumulator` instead a dataframe count function, without success.

The attempts I've made have been:

```
df.columns.foreach(x => {df.filter(df(x).isNull || df(x) === "" || df(x).isNaN) {counter.add(1)} (x, counter.value)})
```

```
df.columns.foreach(x => {df.filter(df(x).isNull || df(x) === "" || df(x).isNaN) {counter.add(1); (x, counter.value)} })
```

Unfortunately none of these work because it doesn't return the correct type (`Array[(String, Long)]`).

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks in advance

P.s. I don't know if using the accumulator is more efficient than the count, but I would just like to try.

Edit: Should I use a `foreach` instead of a `map` to not have a wrong value in the accumulator? Since the `map` is a transformation, while `foreach` is an action

Edit2: As suggested by @DNA I changed the `map` to `foreach` inside my code.

Edit3: Ok, now the problem has become trying to create an `Array[(String, Long)]`. I tried this, but the `:+` operator doesn't work.

```
val counter = session.sparkContext.longAccumulator
val res: Array[(String, Long)] = Array()
df.columns
    .foreach(x => res :+ (x, df.filter{ df(x).isNull || df(x) === "" || df(x).isNaN {counter.add(1); counter.value}}))
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators) discusses this topic:

> Accumulators do not change the lazy evaluation model of Spark. If they
>   are being updated within an operation on an RDD, their value is only
>   updated once that RDD is computed as part of an action. Consequently,
>   accumulator updates are not guaranteed to be executed when made within
>   a lazy transformation like map(). The below code fragment demonstrates this property:

```
val accum = sc.longAccumulator
data.map { x => accum.add(x); x }
// Here, accum is still 0 because no actions have caused the map operation to be computed.
```

There is an additional problem with getting reliable results from accumulators:

> For accumulator updates performed inside actions only, Spark
>   guarantees that each task’s update to the accumulator will only be
>   applied once, i.e. restarted tasks will not update the value. In
>   transformations, users should be aware of that each task’s update may
>   be applied more than once if tasks or job stages are re-executed.

So for both of these reasons, one should favour actions such as `foreach` over transformations such as `map` if using an accumulator like this.

Also, note that you are running `foreach` over the array of columns, not on the DataFrame itself - then you are running the `filter` transformation repeatedly on your DataFrame. So in this case, `foreach` isn't a Spark action at all, it's just a method on `Array`.

So you probably need a `map` over the `df.columns` array (so you get an array to return from your function), then a `foreach` action over the actual DataFrame (to perform the counting).

Here's one way of doing it:

```
df.columns.map(col => {
  val acc = sc.accumulator(0)
  df.foreach(row => {
    val v = row.getAs[Any](col)
    if (v == null || v == "") acc += 1  // NaN left as an exercise
    }
  )
  (col, acc.value)
})
```

But note that this is always going to be inefficient because we have to make a pass over the DataFrame for each column. It would probably be more efficient to count all the columns in a single pass (generating a tuple or Map of counts for each row), then merge the counts using `reduce` or `fold` or similar, rather than using counters.

Comment: Yes in fact I thought of using ```foreach``` instead of ```map```. But I can't return the correct type. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: The function required for `foreach` doesn't need to return anything; the signature is `def
foreach(func: ForeachFunction[T]): Unit` so it's simpler than `map()`

Comment: Sorry, I mean `def foreach(f: (T) ⇒ Unit): Unit`

Comment: Right! Only that I need to have ```countNullValueColumn``` return ```Array[(String,Long)]``` where ```Long``` is the type of ```counter.value```

Comment: Try to see if the 4th edit is what you meant in your previous comment, please @DNA

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I just point out that ```sc.accumulator(0)``` is deprecated so I would replace it with ```sc.longAccumulator```. Now, as for the inefficiently, I'll think about it!